# avoiding duplicated queries in job handle function

Tags: laravel, duplicates, jobs, handle

this handle function counts the number of available cities and areas to each state,  then saves the results in a log file
need to avoid the duplicated queries in this function

```
 public function handle()
{
    $statesIds=State::pluck('id')->toArray();
    
    foreach($statesIds as $stateId){
        $statesIds=State::pluck('id')->toArray();
        $statecitiesIds=City::where('stateId',$stateId)->pluck('id')->toArray();
        $citiesAreasIds=Area::whereIn('cityId',$statecitiesIds)->pluck('id')->toArray();
        $stateName=State::where('id',$stateId)->value('name');
        Log::info($stateName.' had '.count($statecitiesIds).' cities and ' .count($citiesAreasIds) .' areas' );
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Do you have relation for State, City and Area?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Eloquent: Relationships`

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

```
$states = State::query()->with(['cities' => function($query) {
  return $query->with('areas');
}]);
foreach ($states as $state) {
  foreach ($state->city as $city) {
    Log::info($state->name.' had '.count($state->cities).' cities and ' .count($city->areas) .' areas' );
  }
}
```

And add relationships to your Model

```
// State Model
public function cities {
  return $this->hasMany(City::class, 'stateId', 'id');
}
```

And City Model

```
// City Model
public function areas {
  return $this->hasMany(Area::class, 'cityId', 'id');
}
```